# 7zip command line update command not working

Tags: batch-file, executable, 7zip, sfx

I have a simple command in batch to update a single exe in a sfx pack I made (using sfx maker, third party) . There are a few sfx'that need the same file updating to new version / or older, if having to roll back. It's the same file in all. A 99 mb installer  executable.

7za 'archive' -u 'file.com'

So when running, the intended sfx seems to update, you can see the. Tmp file being created however at the end the exe hasn't updated to the new one. The modified date of the new file  is sometimes older too because I need to go back versions. Could that be the reason?

I have to update a separate Config file all the time in them and that works with no problem every time. I'm assuming because  it's newer - edited prior to updating sfx via command.

I have a found I can achieve what I want by running 2 commands, one to delete the exe, another to add the file. But this doubles the processing time.

Is there a way to force the updating even if the target file is older? I couldn't see anything from looking in the help sections.

Is there a certain mode the 7z archive has to be before being used in a sfx creating program. I use store as zip mode and 'add and replace file' option.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

changed u to a and the job is getting done!